# Extracting a url comprised of a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a query string that looks as follows:

```
http://localhost:3000/events?appointment_practices%5B10%5D=Injury&appointment_practices%5B18%5D=Immigration&appointment_practices%5B8%5D=Bankruptcy
```

appointment_practices is actually a hash I inserted into the query string during a redirect:

```
appointment_practices = practices.reduce({}) do |acc, practice|
    acc[practice.id] = practice.class.name
    acc
end
redirect_to events_path(appointment_practices: appointment_practices)
```

Now I want to parse that query string. When I tried to parse it with decode_www_form, it returns an array with a nil element:

```
[nil]
```

This is the code that is giving me the nil element:

```
@http_refer = @_env['HTTP_REFERER']
begin
  uri = URI.parse @http_refer
  practices = Hash[URI::decode_www_form(uri.query)].values_at('appointment_practices')
  puts "practices: #{practices}"
rescue StandardError
end
```

I am trying to extract the hash. For example, in appointment_practices%5B10%5D=Injury, the id is 10 and the practice is Injury.

What other options do I have besides regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query`:

```
require 'uri'
require 'rack'

uri = URI.parse('http://localhost:3000/events?appointment_practices%5B10%5D=Injury&appointment_practices%5B18%5D=Immigration&appointment_practices%5B8%5D=Bankruptcy')
Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(uri.query)
#=> {"appointment_practices"=>{"10"=>"Injury", "18"=>"Immigration", "8"=>"Bankruptcy"}}
```

Comment: I was dabbling around with Rack::Utils.parse_query. But what you have looks even better.